# Is there any way to manipulate a constructor in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm currently working on my assignment and I'm stuck rn. The task is to create a program based on this [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ePcJ.png). In that diagram, as you can see, there is no behavior for creating constructors, but in the given [Main Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF2iA.png) there is. Is there a way to create a program without changing the given Main Class and not creating new methods in addition to the given diagram. The program is to calculate density. Help : )

This is my Box class code:

```
class Box {
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private double depth;
    private double mass;
    private double density;


    public void setWidth(double width){
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height){
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setDepth(double depth){
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    public void setMass(double mass){
        this.mass = mass;
    }

    public double getDensity(){
        density = mass / (width * height * depth);
        return density;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Can I both have a cookie and not have a cookie"? Obviously not. Either [A] add that constructor or [B] change the code in `main`.

Comment: Just define `public Box(...) { }`. A constructor is not a method because it belongs to the class, not a specific instance of the class.

Comment: Define 'manipulate'.

Comment: You can't manipulate a constructor but you can have multiple constructors with a different set of arguments. Also, your class `Box` will always have atleast one default constructor, even when you don't  explicitly create one. This default constructor is defined implicitly as `public Box(){}` and has no arguments.

Comment: The diagram you refer to for `Box` is part of the UML (Unified Modeling Language). It is not uncommon to include methods but skip constructors in Class Diagrams because they tend to be trivial. I would assume that you are allowed to implement a constructor in this exercise even though it does not appear in the diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Main` class you have been given will only work if the `Box` method has a `Box(double, double, double)` constructor.

So you **MUST** add one.

The apparent contradiction with the UML snippet is easy to explain.  UML class diagrams frequently don't show constructors.  My guess is that whoever created that diagram didn't want to clutter it with superfluous detail.

But here is the thing.  Irrespective of what the diagram says, your `Box` class **cannot** work with that `Main` class unless the `Box` class provides the constructors that the `main` method is going to use.

---

To answer the question in the title

> Is there any way to manipulate a constructor in Java?

No there isn't.  At least ... not in the sense that I think you mean.

<sup>In theory, you could use "byte code manipulation" tricks to inject an extra constructor after compilation, but that would be the wrong solution in this context.</sup>